How would you say "for (the benefit of) my future self" in Latin?
I'm looking for a word or phrase to mean "for my future self" to use as an inscription on a keepsake journal/planner. For context, the recipient finds motivation in the question "What would my future self thank me for?" so I am looking for a translation that speaks to that if direct translation is not practical.
I've found 'posteris' which I understand to mean future generations, but haven't been able to find "future self". I suspect it wouldn't be a direct translation and instead need to aim for something like "for (the person) who I will become" or "for who I will be". Would "quid pro fiam/ero" be correct? If 'posteris' is correct for future generations would "pro posteris" mean "for future generations" or is the 'for' implied in 'posteris' alone?
EDIT: Would "pro se futurum" be grammatically correct and mean something like "for one's future self" or "for one's self in the future"?

You are close with your suggestion, but not quite grammatical. The case you want with pro is ablative, not accusative. Pro se futuro is the grammatical form of your suggestion. So "for my future self" would be pro me futuro, or pro me futura if you are female.
